# How to add shortcode in a custom html page?

Tags: html, wordpress, popup, shortcode

I have created a custom page in html and imported it to wordpress. There are a few popup already made by previous developer and I want to use them in my code.

I have already tried just pasting the shortcode in my html code but it is not working.

Is there a way to do this or should I make the popups using html?

Comment: Just use `do_shortcode()` function like: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]'); ?>` where you will replace "my_shortcode" by the name of your shortcode...